Dissolving polygons in python results in some polygons missing
I have a large code that is essentially vectorizing a tiff layer into polygon shapefile. the last step of the code is dissolving the polygons based on their value (ranging 1-5). I tried using 'Geopandas's 'dissolve', 'Shapely' and 'Fiona's 'unary_union' function, I tried 'GDAl's ogr2ogr function and in all of them I get the same issue.
Some of the lower level polygons are being 'Swallowed' by the higher levels. for some reason, in some areas the polygons change their borders and go over the lower levels. this means that in the final output I'm missing some of the poylgons.
The same effect happens when I use the dissolve tool in ArcMap, BUT the same tool in Qgis works perfectly and does not cause this issues.
]
Any ideas how to overcome this issue?
the current code i have that causes the issue:
    def dissolve_shapefiles(self, algo_class):
       """Dissolves merged shapefiles by SM_LV column."""
       try:
           dissolved = self.final_gdf.dissolve(by='SM_LV', as_index=False)
           algo_class.dissolved_output_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.output_directory, "..",
                                                                           self.project_name + '_Vectorized_Dissolved.shp'))
           dissolved.to_file(algo_class.dissolved_output_path)
           full_path = os.path.abspath(algo_class.dissolved_output_path)
           print(f"Dissolved shapefile saved as {algo_class.dissolved_output_path}")
           print(f"Full path: {full_path}")
           self.split_merged_shapefile(algo_class.dissolved_output_path)
       except Exception as e:
           print(f"Error dissolving shapefile: {e}") 


Please add a minimal reproducing example. If possible, with data that helps reproducing it embedded in the script, if the minimal needed data is still too complex for that, as a seperate downloadable file.

In general, make sure you are using the most recent versions of geos, shapely and geopandas.

Quite often there are invalid geometries in a shapefile. For example the "hourglass"-looking shape in the right image seemse to be self-intersecting. It is possible that these geometries are (silently) dropped.

As Sam advised in the comments, the problem was with the geometries.
I used Shapley's 'make_valid' to fix the geometries before dissolving them.
def dissolve_shapefiles(self, algo_class):
    """Dissolves merged shapefiles by SM_LV column."""
    try:

        self.final_gdf['geometry'] = self.final_gdf['geometry'].apply(make_valid)

        dissolved = self.final_gdf.dissolve(by='SM_LV', as_index=False)
        algo_class.dissolved_output_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.output_directory, "..",
                                                                        self.project_name + '_Vectorized_Dissolved.shp'))
        dissolved.to_file(algo_class.dissolved_output_path)
        full_path = os.path.abspath(algo_class.dissolved_output_path)
        print(f"Dissolved shapefile saved as {algo_class.dissolved_output_path}")
        print(f"Full path: {full_path}")
        self.split_merged_shapefile(algo_class.dissolved_output_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error dissolving shapefile: {e}")


FYI: you don't need to use apply. self.final_gdf['geometry'] = self.final_gdf['geometry'].make_valid() will work as well (with recent version of geopandas) and will be faster.
